# Cross-compilation errors with std::async

Tags: c++, arm, cross-compiling, stdasync

### Background

1. I built a toolchain for my ARMv7 Raspberry Pi using crosstool-ng on my Ubuntu 18.04. Due to a [problem with GCC 7.1 compilation of GCC 6.3.0](https://github.com/crosstool-ng/crosstool-ng/issues/735) I did some modifications to ubsan.c file.
2. I built the required libraries on the Raspberry Pi itself, used the [symlink utility](https://github.com/brandt/symlinks) to change symlinks from absolute to relative, compressed the /usr and /lib directories for transfer and installed them in my working sysroot directory.
3. This toolchain has been shown to work for a number of large projects.

### The problem

I have built a simple application using the [paho.mqtt.cpp](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.cpp) library. This application uses the C++11 standard, as required by the library. The application compiles and executes when compiled on my development machine and also when compiled on the Raspberry Pi. However, when I use the abovementioned toolchain, I get an error related to the library's use of std::async.

```
In file included from /home/hicklin/CLionProjects/mqttTest/main.cpp:7:0:
/opt/pi/sysroot/usr/local/include/mqtt/client.h: In member function 'virtual void mqtt::client::connected(const string&)':
/opt/pi/sysroot/usr/local/include/mqtt/client.h:71:76: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class std::future<void>'
   std::async(std::launch::async, &callback::connected, userCallback_, cause);
                                                                            ^
In file included from /opt/pi/sysroot/usr/local/include/mqtt/client.h:28:0,
                 from /home/hicklin/CLionProjects/mqttTest/main.cpp:7:
/opt/pi/x-tools/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/6.3.1/future:115:11: note: declaration of 'class std::future<void>'
     class future;
           ^~~~~~
```

### Attempted fixes

1. I tried using the -nostdinc flag to stop the compiler from using its standard headers and use the ones in the sysroot. The error persisted.
2. I have tried replacing the `future` file referred to in the error with the one installed in the Pi (it only has a very minor difference). The error persisted.

### My question

Would anyone be able to give an indication to the cause of this error and possible things to look into? Should I try to rebuild the toolchain differently or perhaps I am missing some flags?

Comment: The source of the problem has been confirmed to be the cross-compiler. An old colleague of mine gave me his cross-compiler which he built on his machine and it worked fine. I will try to find time to rebuild the cross-compiler to figure out what the exact issue is. I suspect it may be caused due to problems in compiling GCC 6.3 with GCC 7.1.